# How can scrollable of TextField cover the entire height?

Tags: flutter

How do I make the text scroll by holding it from anywhere in the light blue area?

[image]

```
Container(
   height: 50,
   width: 150,
   color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(.1),
   child: TextField(),
)
```